# В ie 9 не работает hover

Tags: html, internet-explorer, css

В ie 9 не работает hover, попробовал csshover.htc, не помогает.
Код такой примерно:

```
<ul> <li id="list"> <a href="index.html"> MENU </a>
<ul id="sub"><li> <a href="index.html"> </a> </li> </ul>
</li></ul>
```

css

```
#list
{
  position:absolute;
  left:-9999px;
}
#list:hover #sub
{
  left: auto;
}
```

Работает везде, кроме ie9.

Comment: @Mixail, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку 101010 редактора.

Comment: Пардон, но с такими параметрами - я даже не знаю, как проверить можно )) Как навести курсор на #list, если он находится в пяти минутах ходьбы от Луны? И чего добиться хотите в итоге? Потому как значение auto - не изменяет положение элемента.

Comment: @Mixail а как вы вообще смогли направить мышь на -9999 пикселей влево :) я тоже хочу научиться так :)

Comment: Извините, а что вы вообще хотите? Я думаю что у вас не правильно составлен код и поэтому не чего не выходит. Скажите что вы хотите, а я вам помогу.

Comment: мышь не надо уводить влево на -9999 пикселей это для того чтобы менюшка уходила туда не знаю куда а при наводке мышкой вернулась на свое место если не верите поставьте на ховер значение авто и увидите код составлен правильно ведь во всех браузерах он работает кроме ie

Comment: аа я понял к чему вы так прикалываетесь))) на самом деле там #sub на -9999пикселей)))

Comment: @Mixail почему-бы не поправить вопрос ?

Answer (score 1):

Используйте:

```
#list a:hover {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Известная проблема в IE `:hover` может применяться только для тега `<a>`, по крайней мере в IE 6 и 7 точно.

Comment: весь прикол в том что у меня там 5 раз используется ховер в 3- х там ваще ссылок нет там тэги h5 и они работают а менюшки оба(гор и верт) в ie че то не реагируют

Comment: обычно такие "недостатки" компенсируют скриптами, ещё может google: hover in ie вам поможет, и ничего Вам не мешает добавить в тег  <h5><a></a></h5> и проверить, в этом ли проблема

Answer (score 0):

Пардонте, не знаю как у вас это работает, да ещё и во всех браузерах кроме IE9. У меня Ваш чудокод не пашет ни в одном браузере.

Вам правильно сказали про сдвиг мыши на `-9999` пикселей, ведь именно там окажется Ваш элемент списка для которого вы задаёте `hover`, и навести на него курсор не будет возможным.

Опишите задачу: что вы хотите добиться...? Я бы эффект выезжающего элемента делал всё же с помощью `jQuery`, ибо не уверен, что с помощью `css` можно сделать это плавно и красиво. Если плавность вам не важна, то юзайте элементарные функции JS. Изначально задайте "невидимому" элементу `display:none`, а при наведении с помощью `JS` задавайте `display:block`.